"Как всегда" в этом предложении - часть сказуемого или вводное слово?
Все было как всегда: быстро и весело.

если бы оно было вводным, наверное его стоило бы обособить?

Совершенно верно. Я потому и задаю вопрос, чтоб узнать, надо ли его обособлять.

Здесь как всегда является сказуемым. Запятая не ставится. Вводное слово как всегда указывает на регулярность какого-то события, синонимично фразам "как обычно", "как правило". Его легко убрать из предложения без потери смысла.
